# Remove similar characters from list

Tags: c#

I am making a app to generate a password

Now I have a character list which use the following characters when all options for generate a password are null:

```
  chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
```

Next I have a else with some options like Punctuation and Symbols, so then he is not using the standard characters:

```
var listOfCharacters = string.Empty;

foreach (var currentOption in options)
{
    switch (currentOption)
    {

        case GenOptions.Punctuation:
             listOfCharacters += "&@.#%!*?;:,";
             break;
        case GenOptions.Symbols:
             listOfCharacters += "^$";
             break;       
        default:
             break; 
    }
}

chars = listOfCharacters.ToCharArray();

listOfCharacters.Remove('i'); listOfCharacters.Remove('!');  
listOfCharacters.Remove('l'); listOfCharacters.Remove('1'); 
listOfCharacters.Remove('O'); listOfCharacters.Remove('o'); 
listOfCharacters.Remove('0'); listOfCharacters.Remove('q');
listOfCharacters.Remove('p'); listOfCharacters.Remove('g');    
listOfCharacters.Remove('I');
```

Now I want to build in a option to remove Similar characters so characters who are almost a copy from each other like o and 0. I have want to do this with listofcharacter.remove but when I use it like above it gives me a error because its null/empty. Now how can I fix this?

Comment: Which line gives you the 'null/empty' message?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `null/empty` error messages.

You are trying to use [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx), which takes character index as an argument. So, when you pass `'i'` it is first converted to int and then `String.Remove` tries to delete character with that index. As far as I understand it's not what you want it to do.

You can use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) instead:

```
String.Replace('!',String.Empty);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
listOfCharacters.Replace('i',' ');
```

Comment: If you are asking a question then it should be a comment instead.

Comment: It is not a question, i am asking you to use it.